# Python statsmodels installation gives import error on pandas

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to install statsmodels (http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net) using easy_install (as recommended here: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/install.html). I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Problem is that I'm getting an ImportError on pandas:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1094, in run_setup
  run_setup(setup_script, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 30, in run_setup
  lambda: execfile(
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 72, in run
  return func()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 32, in <lambda>
  {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
File "setup.py", line 201, in <module>
File "setup.py", line 53, in check_dependency_versions
ImportError: statsmodels requires pandas
```

However, I already have Pandas installed (albeit built from source rather than through easy_install):

```
>>> import pandas
>>> pandas.__version__
    '0.10.1'
>>> pandas.__path__
    ['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas']
```

I suspect easy_install is looking at the wrong directories but I'm not sure how to go about changing the settings. Am I correct? If not, what could be the problem?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Edit - here's the location of easy_install, pip and python respectively:

```
x@ubuntu:~$ which easy_install
/usr/bin/easy_install
x@ubuntu:~$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip
x@ubuntu:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `which python` and `which pip` please? The source of this is usually that pip/easy_install are associated with one python interpreter and you are using the other.

Comment: Also, `easy_install` is on death row. Use pip instead.

Comment: @mbatchkarov Interesting. I've made an edit with the information but it seems to me they are installed correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` (see your second pasted block), which most likely means there is a python interpreter in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/`. However, your `easy_install` is in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` (first line in your first pasted block), meaning there is another python interpreter in `"/usr/lib/python2.7`.

I believe the problem stems from the fact that `pandas` has been installed for the first python interpreter, `easy_install` refers to the second and is trying to install `statsmodels` for the second interpreter.

The reason I asked to see the output of `which python` is to check which of he multiple python installations is your default one. Based on your edited post, I think `/usr/bin/python` is a symlink to `/usr/local/python` or something like that. You can verify that by running `ls -l /usr/bin | grep python`.

The solution is to choose one of your interpreters and use it and only it. Since one is already set as your default (i.e. get called when you open a terminal and type `python`), I suggest you use that. Then [install pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html)- see section "Using get-pip". Then use pip to install statsmodels: `sudo pip install statsmodels`. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! That's very well explained! I've actually solved the problem before you posted by using pip to install both statsmodels (and patsy as it turns out to be another dependency). However, your explanation has helped me to understand the root of the problem! Thank you very much for your help! Much appreciated!