# statsmodels installed but cannot be imported

Tags: python, statsmodels

First, I installed the dependencies of statsmodels: pandas, patsy, and cython.

Second, I installed statsmodels.

And now when I import statsmodels I get:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------    -----
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c7407a2ff2ab> in <module>()
----> 1 import statsmodels

ImportError: No module named statsmodels
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601825/python-statsmodels-installation-gives-import-error-on-pandas?rq=1?

Comment: I had to reinstall `statsmodels` using `pip`. Thanks!